# How to create price comparison website using opencart 2.x

Tags: php, web-services, api, amazon-web-services, opencart2.x

I am using **OpenCart** for development.

I have affiliate API of Amazon,ebay,Flipkart and Snapdeal. I want to combine all API results to my web page with pagination. Like this website https://www.compareraja.in/mobiles.html.

My question is :

1. Should I save all API results in the database.?
2. Is there any method to combine all API results in a shuffled manner and display 1st 10 results then next 10 on load more option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you should save all api results in database like you add product in admin panel. because there is some limitation to call api, for example limit of 5 call per second. what happen if your site traffic exceed api call limit, so always save api result to database for better performance. You should consider [InterStore](http://www.interstore-engine.com/) extension for plug & play solution.
2. If you have imported products from api to database, you don't need to create pagination because opencart already have this functionality

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)